# Is “the” needed when talking about someone's abstract belongings?

Tags: articles, definite-article

I’ve got this text:

> In September it turned out that Judy won a scholarship that would
> cover her tuition and board. I was really glad for her because only a
> few students had this chance. Judy said she wanted to become more
> independent so this scholarship would be very helpful. I can
> understand her intention because it seems very embarrassing to spend
> **money** of someone who isn’t even your relative.

Now I’m struggling about whether I need to put the article before “money” in the last sentence. I’d rather not do it because there is no concrete relative or money, but a friend insists that the situation is concrete enough to put the article.

Comment: You might want to brush up on contractions: to spend someone's money when they are  not even your relative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In September it turned out that Judy won a scholarship that would cover her tuition and board. I was really glad for her because only a few students had this chance. Judy said she wanted to become more independent so this scholarship would be very helpful. I can understand her intention because it seems very embarrassing to spend money of someone who isn’t even your relative.

Although the passage does not clearly name that *someone* in *money of someone who isn’t even your relative*, I tend to interpret that that person's identity is known.  The noun phrase

> someone who isn’t even your relative

with the intensifier, *even*, suggests that the potential benefactor has been identified, and a determiner could be required.

@Lambie's suggestion to use the possessive *someone's* should work well here.

https://grammar.collinsdictionary.com/easy-learning/nouns-used-without-a-determiner

> Singular nouns that are uncountable are used without a determiner when you are making a general reference.
> Do you like jelly?

In our case here, I feel that the zero-determiner rule probably could not be applied.